# Considerations when programming back testing engine

Tags: testing

I am at the beginning of writing a back testing engine and wanted to get some Feed back on considerations I should take into account , design ideas etc.

Comment: Hi GKonheiser, welcome to Quant.SE! I'm afraid this is too broad to get a good answer, could you please narrow it down a bit?

Comment: Hi sorry , yes that was very broad. so with regards to data storage my thinking is: I have my tick data in a csv format , at run time I will I load the data/instrument I want to test into an array. From the tick data I will build any other time frames I need. Would this be the fastest way to handle the data, is this a good concept or should I be looking at storing the data in a data base?